# Sequelize: setter for association does not update simple member for it

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have `Students` and `Classes` with a hasMany association between them.
I do this:

```
myStudent.setClasses(ids). then(function(result) {
   console.log(myStudent.Classes);
});
```

**Questions:**

1. What does `result` parameter mean inside the then-handler?
2. Why isn't `myStudent.Classes` up-to-date with the `setClasses()` change I made?
3. How can I have Sequelize update the simple `Classes` member? I need to return a simple JSON response to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#associating-objects), `result` would be the associated `Classes` (in you case) when sending them to the `.setClasses` method.

   Therefore, your `ids` param should be in fact the `Classes`, perhaps you should require them before

   ```
   Class.findAll({where: {id: ids}})
     .on('success', function (classes) {
       myStudent.setClasses(classes)
         .on('success', function (newAssociations) {
           // here now you will have the new classes you introduced into myStudent
           // you say you need to return a JSON response, maybe you could send this new associations
         })
       })
   ```
2. It's not updating because the queries regarding the associations of objects doesn't rely on you original object (`myStudent`). You should add the new associations (`result` var, in your example, `newAssociations`, in mine) in your existing `myStudent.Classes` array. Maybe [reloading](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/#reloading-instances) your instance should work as well.

   ```
   Class.findAll({where: {id: ids}})
     .on('success', function (classes) {
       myStudent.setClasses(classes)
         .on('success', function (newAssociations) {
           myStudent.Classes = myStudent.Classes || [];
           myStudent.Classes.push(newAssociations);
           // guessing you're not using that myStudent obj anymore
           res.send(myStudent);
         })
     })
   ```
3. I hope I answered this one with the previous two answers, if not, could you explain what you mean by updating the `Classes` member?